How to dynamically create Quarto code chunk options
I want to create some functions for my team that standardize Quarto code chunk options. Is this possible? I want to control not just label, echo, and eval, but I want to include some other options like setting the classes argument based on the input content.
```{r}
cat("#| eval: false")
cat("#| classes: my-class")
mtcars
```

I basically want to find a way to get this function to work.
my_quarto_chunk <- function(eval = T, echo = F, classes = NULL, ...){
  # Set chunk options  
  cat("```{r}")
  cat("#| eval:", eval)
  cat("#| echo:", echo)
  cat("#| classes:", classes)
  
  # Code to execute / display in this code chunk
  ...
  
  cat("```")
}  


I'm still not quite sure how you want this to work.  If (say) eval is defined in the current environment, then  #| eval: !expr 'eval' should work (see https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6193), but I'm not sure how your my_quarto_chunk() function integrates with the rest of the document ...

Hi Ben, thanks for the clarifying question. I see that !expr 'eval' does work, but I want to be able to create a "pre-constructed" code chunk with options that are set in advance, so that I can give my team a set of functions to use in different situations, where they don't necessarily want to know how the complexities of code chunk options work. In the example I provided, I'm more concerned with dynamically changing the 'classes' options, but the options I'm envisioning will include eval, echo, figure sizes and captions.
